# Using Bootstrap dual listbox with ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, listbox

I added the [Bootstrap dual listbox plugin](http://www.virtuosoft.eu/code/bootstrap-duallistbox/) on my project and it's working fine, but how can I pass the contents of the selected listbox to my controller? It's already inside a form but if I try to get it through FormCollection it returns as null.

View:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-7" style="margin-left: -15px;">
    <select style="display: none;" multiple="multiple" size="10" name="dualListbox" id="dualListbox" class="demo2">
        @if (ViewData["Customers"] != null)
        {
            foreach (var item in ViewData["Customers"] as List<Testbox.Models.Customer>)
            {
                <option value="customer">@item.NAME @item.LName - @item.PHONE11</option>
            }
        }
    </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Well you can do it as below:

I'll assume that your `form id` is `demoform` and below is how the `post` action method will look like:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetForm()
{
       string values = Request.Form["dualListbox"];
       //Form[key] will be 'name' property of your select box

       //You will get values as comma ',' separated values like option 1,
       //option 2, option 4 etc., and I hope you know how you can get each 
       //options by splitting the comma separated values.
       ......
       ......
}
```

Comment: For some reason this also returns as null. I might be doing something wrong, but from what I've seen this plugin takes a Listbox and splits it in two. Say, if my original one was named "myList", it creates two lists named "myList_helper1" and "myList_helper2". I tried writing `string values = Request.Form["dualListbox_helper1"];` but it still comes up as null.

Comment: I created a VS project for this and followed the same step as mentioned in docs!! and it worked for me!! I think either the problem might be because of adding options dynamically or the `value` you are adding to each of your option is same where as its different in demo!! so try adding a dynamic `values` to your option!! Hope you got it @NikolMarg

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work when I use this plugin. When I remove the script and keep it as a simple `<select>` element it works, but when I turn it to a dual listbox with the plugin it doesn't.

Comment: No Nikol!! Just try what I said!! Give unique `option value` like `<option value="customer1">....</option> <option value="customer2">..</option>` Like that...

Comment: I tried that already and that's not the problem. The only way it seems to work is when I don't use the plugin at all and I want to keep using it if possible. I tried to give all options different values dynamically and I also tried to put all options manually instead of doing it by code. Still nothing.

Comment: Can you update your code along with `form` and its contents??

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example to your question. Maybe this will help people in the future.
The trick is in the JS.

Let's say you want to use [Bootstrap Dual Listbox](http://www.virtuosoft.eu/code/bootstrap-duallistbox/) in conjuction with ASP.NET MVC 4 and Kendo framework.

We will use the Razor syntax and C#.

First, we write in the view the placeholder for the code. We will be linking a kendo control and the [Bootstrap Dual Listbox](http://www.virtuosoft.eu/code/bootstrap-duallistbox/)

```
<script>
    var urlGetCascadeMultiSelectBrandTypeByBrand = "@(Url.Action("GetCascadeMultiSelectBrandTypeByBrand", "DropDownList"))";
</script>

<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 padding-0 ">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.BrandId)<br />
        @(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m.BrandId)
    .DataSource(source =>
    {
        source.Read(read =>
        {
            read.Action("GetCascadeDdlBrandBySegment", "DropDownList")
                .Data("filterSegments");
        })
        .ServerFiltering(true);
    })
    .DataTextField("BrandName")
    .DataValueField("BrandId")
    .Filter(FilterType.Contains)
    .CascadeFrom("SegmentId")
    .OptionLabel("Select brand")
    .Events(evt => evt.Change("onBrandIdDdlChange"))
    .HtmlAttributes(new { @style = "width: 100%;" }))
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.BrandId)
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        &nbsp;
    </div>
</div>

<div class="clear height10"></div>

<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 padding-0 ">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">

        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.BrandTypeIdList)<br />
        @if (Model.IsEdit)
        {
            @Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.BrandTypeIdList, Html.GetBrandTypeByBrandIdSelectListItemsList(Model.BrandId))

        }
        else
        {
            @Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.BrandTypeIdList, new List<SelectListItem>())
        }

        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.BrandTypeIdList)
    </div>
</div>
```

Then, we create the C# helper code to go with it.

```
public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetBrandTypeByBrandIdSelectListItemsList(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, int brandId)
{
    using (var dbContext = new Entities())
    {
        return dbContext.BrandType.Where(x => x.Active == true && x.BrandId == brandId).Select(BrandTypeToDdlSelector).ToList();
    }
}

public static Func<BrandType, SelectListItem> BrandTypeToDdlSelector
{
    get
    {
        return (x => new SelectListItem()
        {
            Value = x.BrandTypeId.ToString(),
            Text = x.Name
        });
    }
}

public JsonResult GetCascadeMultiSelectBrandTypeByBrand(int? brandId)
{
    var brandTypesList = DbContext.BrandType.Where(p => p.Active == true);

    if (brandId != null)
    {
        brandTypesList = brandTypesList.Where(p => p.BrandId == brandId);
    }

    return Json(brandTypesList.Select(x => new { BrandTypeId = x.BrandTypeId, BrandTypeName = x.Name }), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Then we create the JS code to manipulate the HTML at runtime and bind the selected values to the MVC model.

```
var brandTypeIdDualListbox = new Object();

$(document).ready(function ()
{   
    //we create the dual list control
    brandTypeIdDualListbox = $('select[name="BrandTypeIdList"]').bootstrapDualListbox({
    nonSelectedListLabel: 'Non-selected',
    selectedListLabel: 'Selected',
    preserveSelectionOnMove: 'moved',
    moveOnSelect: false,    
    });

    //we setup the change event for the control
    $('select[name="BrandTypeIdList').on('change', function (args)
    {
        //we traverse every option
        $("#BrandTypeIdList option").each(function (index,element)
        {
            //we check if the element has the `data-sortindex` attribute
            if (!!$(element).attr('data-sortindex'))
                $(element).attr('selected', 'selected');
            else
                $(element).removeAttr('selected');
        });
    })
});


function filterBrands()
{
    var brandId = $("#BrandId").val();
    if (brandId == "")
        brandId = "-1";
    return {
        BrandId: brandId
    };
}

function populateBrandTypeIdDualListbox()
{
    $.getJSON(urlGetCascadeMultiSelectBrandTypeByBrand, filterBrands(), function (data)
    {
        var items;
        $.each(data, function (i, item)
        {
            brandTypeIdDualListbox.append("<option value=" + item.BrandTypeId/*Value*/ + ">" + item.BrandTypeName/*Key or Text*/ + "</option>");
        });
        brandTypeIdDualListbox.trigger('bootstrapDualListbox.refresh', true); // we refresh the control
    });
}

function onBrandIdDdlChange(evt)
{
    var brandIdDropDownList = $("#BrandId").data("kendoDropDownList");

    $('#BrandTypeIdList').empty();
    brandTypeIdDualListbox.trigger('bootstrapDualListbox.refresh', true);
    if ($("#BrandId").val() == "" || $("#BrandId").val() == "-1")
    {
        //if no value is selected we disable the control
        $(".bootstrap-duallistbox-container").find("*").prop("disabled", true);
    }
    else
    {
        populateBrandTypeIdDualListbox();
        $(".bootstrap-duallistbox-container").find("*").prop("disabled", false); // we enable the control

    }
}
```